# Password Protected Directory Lister

Tags: javascript, java, php, html

I am making a directory Lister!

Here is my website [Website](http://mjdb.hostei.com)

I have done implementing php code successfully on this website.

[image]

But now i have to password protect that page ! I need help how to do it!

If i make a simple php/html file for redirecting to the directory lister , people will see the link, and can bypass from entering password, and will directly visit the directory link!

But i have to Lock the whole page , what should I do!

Extra:

I want first open a page where are two buttons:

- Access Directory
- FTP Login

On clicking access login it will prompt for password and will enter the directory!

Answer (score 2):

Time to learn about `$_SESSION` and `$_POST`

You can authenticate users in one of two ways/

### $_SESSION

use php to create a cookie and corresponding user data info on the server, in order to make sure you know who you're talking to. You'll have to use this approach with a password of some sort.

Have a page that has a password go to a submit page

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="password" name="pass" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

login.php will look like

```
<?php
session_start(); //this starts a session for any user visiting the page
if (!$_POST["pass"] === "mypassword") { //if the user got there with no password
    die(); //kill the page
}
//anything after here will only be shown to people who input "mypassword"
//at this point we can give the user a piece of data so they can access other
//parts of the site with
$_SESSION["auth"] = true;
```

Anything you put into the session thing will only be for that user individually. Now in the protected part of your site, you can

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION["auth"]) {
    echo "you don't have priveleges to come here!";
    die();
}
//authenticated users continue to roped off part.
```

### $_POST

You can also use post, much like above, but doing so will not remember a user if they move away from your page. (They'll have to relogin)

```
if (!$_POST["pass"] === "mypassword") { //if the user got there with no password
    die(); //kill the page
}
//anything after here will only be shown to people who input "mypassword"
```